# How can I get an up-to-date version of wget on Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, wget, tls

On Cygwin, the most up-to-date version of `wget` that I can find is `1.19.1`.
https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/wget.html

However, that version is lacking support for TLS 1.3, which was added in `1.19.5`, to name just one example:

> - Enable TLS1.3 with recent OpenSSL environment

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2018-05/msg00007.html

How can I get a more up-to-date version of `wget`? (I would prefer through Cygwin, since I use a script to automatically update my toolchain through Cygwin.)

Comment: It does not appear that a pre-compiled version of 1.19.5 has been released.  So you will have to compile it yourself. If it exists then it's not linked on the Cygwin website.  I am sure the Cygwin developers would appreciate being notified their website only links to a version of wget from 2017.

Comment: @Ramhound: thanks for the suggestion. They are proposing a *mailing list* as their primary point of contact, though - as if they are trying to make it extra difficult to contact them...

Comment: Why do you find difficult to use a mailing list ? If you ask there and explain your need the maintainer of wget will likely update the package